# Calling GEOquerry error while loading the library

Tags: r, bioconductor, geoquery

*Note: this question has also been asked on [Biostars](https://www.biostars.org/p/494967/)*

I started getting a strange error when trying to load GEOquerry with `library(GEOquerry)`.

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘GEOquery’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]): namespace ‘rlang’ 0.4.9 is already loaded, but >= 0.4.10 is required
```

When I run `> devtools::install_github('r-lib/rlang')` I get ...

```
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  namespace ‘rlang’ 0.4.9 is already loaded, but >= 0.4.10 is required
```

Has anyone dealt with this before?  Restarting my R session has no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rlang 0.4.10 is the current version at CRAN: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rlang/index.html

Try to install it via `install.packages`, not via GitHub directly.